# Controlling number of recipients in a Share sheet

Tags: ios, sms, share, uiactivity

I want to control the number of recipients in the Message Share sheet in iOS. Is that possible? Or once it is handed off for sharing it is out of your control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible.